# How to increase model's validation accuracy?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, semantic-similarity

I'm trying to build a model for text similarity problem using CNN, Bi-directional GRU and Bi-directional LSTM. I've tried changing several parameters but I'm getting the maximum validation accuracy as 0.77. I'm using MSE as loss function. Can anyone suggest what do I need to do to improve my model's validation accuracy?

Details:

1. Dataset: Quora Question Pairs (around 400K examples).
2. Dataset split: 80% for training and 20% for testing.
3. Pre-trained embeddings: Google News vectors (dimension: 300).
4. Input text vector dimension: 300.

Following is the code for my model:

````
dropout = 0.5

def build_model_A():
  inp1 = Input(shape = (max_length,))
  embd1 = Embedding(len(embeddings), embd_dim, weights = [embeddings],\
                input_length = max_length, trainable = False)(inp1)
  sp_drop1 = SpatialDropout1D(dropout)(embd1)

  # GRU
  rnn1 = GRU(128, return_sequences = True)(sp_drop1)
  rnn2 = GRU(128, return_sequences = True)(rnn1)
  bn1 = BatchNormalization()(rnn2)

  drop1 = Dropout(dropout)(bn1)

  # CNN
  conv1 = Conv1D(64, kernel_size = 4, activation = 'relu',\
                 kernel_initializer = 'he_uniform')(drop1)
  conv2 = Conv1D(64, kernel_size = 4, activation = 'relu',\
                 kernel_initializer = 'he_uniform')(conv1)
  max_pool1 = MaxPooling1D(2)(conv2)

  drop2 = Dropout(dropout)(max_pool1)

  gl_avg_pool1 = GlobalAveragePooling1D()(drop2)
  gl_max_pool1 = GlobalMaxPooling1D()(drop2)

  concat1 = concatenate([gl_avg_pool1, gl_max_pool1])

  dense1 = Dense(1, activation = 'sigmoid')(concat1)

  model_A = Model(inputs = inp1, outputs = dense1, name = 'model_A')

  return model_A

def build_model_B():
  inp1 = Input(shape = (max_length,))
  embd1 = Embedding(len(embeddings), embd_dim, weights = [embeddings],\
                input_length = max_length, trainable = False)(inp1)
  sp_drop1 = SpatialDropout1D(dropout)(embd1)

  # LSTM
  rnn1 = LSTM(128, return_sequences = True)(sp_drop1)
  rnn2 = LSTM(128, return_sequences = True)(rnn1)
  bn1 = BatchNormalization()(rnn2)

  drop1 = Dropout(dropout)(bn1)

  # CNN
  conv1 = Conv1D(64, kernel_size = 4, activation = 'relu',\
                 kernel_initializer = 'he_uniform')(drop1)
  conv2 = Conv1D(64, kernel_size = 4, activation = 'relu',\
                 kernel_initializer = 'he_uniform')(conv1)
  max_pool1 = MaxPooling1D(2)(conv2)

  drop2 = Dropout(dropout)(max_pool1)

  gl_avg_pool1 = GlobalAveragePooling1D()(drop2)
  gl_max_pool1 = GlobalMaxPooling1D()(drop2)

  concat1 = concatenate([gl_avg_pool1, gl_max_pool1])

  dense1 = Dense(1, activation = 'sigmoid')(concat1)

  model_B = Model(inputs = inp1, outputs = dense1, name = 'model_B')

  return model_B

def build_full_model():
  inp1 = Input(shape = (max_length,))
  inp2 = Input(shape = (max_length,))

  model_A = build_model_A()
  model_B = build_model_B()

  model_A_out = model_A(inp1)
  model_B_out = model_B(inp2)

  lambda1 = Lambda(euclidean_distance, name='euclidean_distance')\
  ([model_A_out, model_B_out])

  full_model = Model(inputs = [inp1, inp2], outputs = lambda1, name = 'full_model')
  full_model.summary()

  full_model.compile(loss = 'mse', optimizer = Adam(learning_rate = 1e-3),\
                metrics = ['acc'])

  return full_model
```
````